# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Clubs and Users)

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

## User Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `town` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=55 ;
```

## Club Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clubs` (
  `clubId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clubName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `startTime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `finishTime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clubId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

## memberid Table

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `membersid` (
  `memberId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clubId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberId`,`clubId`,`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `memberId` (`memberId`),
  KEY `clubId` (`clubId`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `clubId_2` (`clubId`),
  KEY `clubId_3` (`clubId`),
  KEY `userId_2` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

## DAO

```
String query = "INSERT INTO membersid( userId, clubId ) VALUES ( ?,? )";
```

Keep getting error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
If someone could be that would be great:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keys in the `membersid` table (please change that name to `members`) are messed up. Try

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members 
(
  `memberId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `clubId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY (`clubId`,`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```